# How do I connect to the Ubuntu One server-side CouchDB?

Tags: ubuntu-one, couchdb

How do i connect to the ubuntuone couch on the ubuntu server side (the one my local desktopcouch replicates with)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We'll soon be putting together some proper documentation for this. In the meantime, you can use a tool named ubuntuone-couchdb-query to get at your CouchDBs at Ubuntu One. You can download ubuntuone-couchdb-query from http://ubuntuone.com/p/Gyx/.

If you're looking for more technical information (that is, how you'd connect to your in-the-cloud Ubuntu One CouchDBs from your own programs), please clarify your question, and I can explain how ubuntuone-couchdb-query works in more detail.

Comment: This is well commented, I understand it quite nicely. Thank you